# Lex and yacc how to solve shift/reduce dangling else

Tags: grammar, yacc, lex, reduce, shift

I've found similar examples to my question but I can't seem to apply it to my example.

Could someone help point me in the right direction?

Here's the y.output error message:

```
state 97
ifstatement : IF LPAREN conditionalexpr RPAREN statement .  (23)
ifstatement : IF LPAREN conditionalexpr RPAREN statement . ELSE statement  (24)

ELSE  shift 102
IF  reduce 23
INT  reduce 23
OUTPUT  reduce 23
WHILE  reduce 23
IDENTIFIER  reduce 23
INT_LITERAL_TOK  reduce 23
LPAREN  reduce 23
LBRACE  reduce 23
RBRACE  reduce 23
SEMICOLON  reduce 23
DBL_PLUS  reduce 23
DBL_MINUS  reduce 23
MINUS  reduce 23
```

Here's my grammar:
    statement:
    block |
    emptystatement | 
    ifstatement |
    whilestatement | 
    statementexpression SEMICOLON |
    OUTPUT LPAREN addexprlist RPAREN SEMICOLON
    ;

```
addexprlist:
addexpr |
addexprlist COMMA addexpr
;

emptystatement:
SEMICOLON
;

ifstatement:
IF LPAREN conditionalexpr RPAREN statement |
IF LPAREN conditionalexpr RPAREN statement ELSE statement
;
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't need to be resolved. S/R conflicts are warnings, and the default action *(shift)* is the default precisely because of this case.

You can use the following statement to deal with the warning:

```
%expect 1 /* or whatever */
```

Comment: So there is no solution to get rid of this warning?

Comment: Thanks for that, but I'm hoping to modify the grammar to fix the ambiguity without silencing the warning if possible.

Comment: I just don't know how to modify the grammar to accomplish that as of yet :/

Answer (score 0):

I ended up modifying the grammar to this:

```
ifstatement:
matched |
unmatched
;

matched:
IF LPAREN conditionalexpr RPAREN matched ELSE matched 
;

unmatched: 
IF LPAREN conditionalexpr RPAREN matched |
IF LPAREN conditionalexpr RPAREN unmatched |
IF LPAREN conditionalexpr RPAREN matched ELSE unmatched
;
```

I believe it should still work correctly and has fixed the shift/reduce error :)